# Trying to encapsulate an email in <>

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull a first name, last name, and email from a data base and trying to put into Firstname Lastname , with PHP. Every time I try to echo the data I only get Firstname Lastname. The email and <> doesn't show up? Anyone know how I can echo .

Here's the code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
     echo      $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " <" . $row['email'] . ">,";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but `<` and `>` characters form a HTML tag, that is why you don't see the mail.

If you look at the source code of your echo, you will see the `<mail>` appearing.

---

You can also do this :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
     echo      htmlspecialchars($row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " <" . $row['email'] . ">,");
}
```

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will transform `<` and `>` to their HTML code, so they will be visible even if you're not looking at the source.

---

A useful function to have is this one :

```
// Echoes the string in a HTML friendly way
function echoHTML($str)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($str);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echoHTML($row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " <" . $row['email'] . ">,");
}
```

---

PS : be careful about the last comma if you want to concatenate email adresses, you will have a trailing `,` at the end of the list of mails. Here is how to avoid it :

```
$adresses = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    // No more "," here
    $adresses[] = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " <" . $row['email'] . ">";
}

echoHTML(implode(', ', $adresses));
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I found ascii code for both the < and the >

Comment: I tried as you suggested with the htmlspecialchars but the mail function will not let me send. I tried it on my local server and it works just fine. I am using godaddy servers

Comment: It's normal. `htmlspecialchars` is only meant to help you display the values on the screen.
Use it to visually make sure you have done the right thing with the string, but don't use it inside the `mail` function.

Comment: Everything looks fine. I need to be able to send via that format. Is there some special code for godaddy's mail servers that I am missing?